# Как сделать столбец по времени с условиями? В какой тип данных перевести, чтобы посчитать

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

При расчете стоит 2 задачи:

1. есть отдельный столбец "Время". Нужно посчитать по нему разницу. Например, от каждой даты нужно начинать сначала, те первая ноль, а дальше 1- предыдущая дата - это будет колонка время. Далее нужно посчитать накопительно этот столбец через cumsum. Сделала и функцию и потом через apply, но все равно выдает ошибки.
2. По  полученному накопительному шагу, нужно создать столбец с критериями, если  накопительная сумма равна 7 минут, то 1, если <= 14 мин., то 2 и т. д. Здесь через where не получается, пишет для типа данных dt не работает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Присвоение это не `==` это просто `=`

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть тестом , а не картинкой. за скриншот  - минус

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понял вопрос, но у вас в функции с первого фото явно несколько ошибок, вот исправленный вариант:

```
def sd(s):
    sha_cons = 0
    if s['time_cumsum'] <= pd.to_datetime('00:07:00', format='%H:%M:%S').to_pydatetime().time():
        sha_cons = 1
    if s['time_cumsum'] <= pd.to_datetime('00:14:00', format='%H:%M:%S').to_pydatetime().time():
        sha_cons = 2
    return sha_cons
```

1. вы почему то поменяли название переменной с sha_cons, которое использовалось в начале, на shaot_cons
2. вы почему то не присваиваете переменной новое значение а проверяете-равно ли значение 2 или 1

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. за поправку в функции. У меня там всё равно TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'. Я никак не пойму как исправить, даже перевод в тип dt не помогает.

Comment: @Любитель все из за разных типов данных в столбце используется datetime, а сравнение происходит со строкой, сейчас исправлю ответ, чтобы работало корректно

Comment: @Любитель исправил, по идее должно работать, учтите формат данных datetime должен совпадать, в данном случае я указал "format='%H:%M:%S'" но у вас он может отличаться, я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в datetime хотя в целом pandas более менее знаю.

Comment: @ Step1709, большое вам спасибо. Что-то считает, сейчас посмотрю, можно было бы в экселе это посчитать, но там массив данных большой, виснет и все. Сама в теме дат не сильна, буду дальше копать.

Comment: @Любитель не за что) Если б лучше знал способы работы с датами и временем в пандас-смог бы лучше помочь)